# Remove link 'add your review' from upsell product grid in magento product view page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, review

I am displaying upsell product in product view page in grid format. Now problem is by using code

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_link, 'short') ?>
```

it displays me 2 links under product image.

first is number of reviews in **'x' review(s)** format and 
second link is **'add your review'**.

I want to remove **'add your review'** link, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've just added 'short' to getReviewsSummaryHtml($_link,) ?> in upsell.phtml file and it just shows 'x' reviews(s) without 'add your review' link, how you wanted it to work. Magento 1.8.0.0